# Insert statement with automatically generated columns

Tags: php, dynamic, insert

I want to create an INSERT statement using the columns of my table and NULL or blank values for the content except for the id, created_by .etc. I am trying to avoid duplicates. Right now I get:

```
INSERT INTO testimonials (id, created, created_by, id, quote, name, position, company, published, created, created_by, last_modified_by, last_modified) VALUES ('257927816', NOW(), '1', '')
```

and I would like to have blank values iterate in the VALUES section for everything but the first 3, which I define.

```
function insertBlankWithID($table, $postFxn) {
    global $randomID;
    $id = $randomID;
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
    if (!$resultInsert) {
        echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-error">'.QUERY_ERROR.'</div>';
        include($cmsdir . FOOTER_EXIT);
        exit();
    }
    $columns = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultInsert)) {
        if (empty($columns)) {
            $columns = array_keys($row);
        }
    }
    //$sql = 'INSERT INTO `testimonials` (`id`, `quote`, `name`, `position`, `company`, `published`, `created`, `created_by`, `last_modified_by`, `last_modified`) VALUES ('.$id.', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);';
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (id, created, created_by, %s) VALUES ('".$id."', NOW(), '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '%s')", $table, implode(', ', $columns), implode("',  '", ''));
    mysql_query($sql);
    /*
    if (!$sql) {
        echo '<div class="ec-messages messages-error">'.QUERY_ERROR.'</div>';
        exit();
    }
    */
    echo $sql;
}
// redirect(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php").'?s=output&id='.$id

insertBlankWithID('testimonials', $postFxn);
```

Comment: I do need to ask, why do you have a global for the insert id instead of using [MySQLs AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to prevent duplicates?

Comment: its more of an obscurity, then security measure, i realize its probably not the best method, but i prefer it to auto_increment, and my db is so small the chances for duplicates are really negligible.

Comment: Ahh. ok. ^^ Did the answer provided help, or should I add clarification? (or come up with a different answer if it doesn't help at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you should limit the `select` to 1, (ie `$resultInsert = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table. " limit 1");` as you don't need the information, just the keys.  That removes the need for the `while` loop.

Now, to get all the keys except the first three, for your `$columns` variable, use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) such as `$columns = array_slice($columns, 3);`  Or, if it isn't the first three when you `select *`, you can do `$columns = array_diff($columns, array('id', 'created', 'created_by') );`

Now, to insert `null` after the first three, you are imploding a string - which won't work, instead you can make an array of null values matching the count of the new `$columns` such as:

```
$blanks = array_fill(0, count($columns), 'null');
```

and when creating your statement, do `implode(", ", $blanks)`, which would make your `$sql` look like:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (id, created, created_by, %s) VALUES ('".$id."', NOW(), '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '%s')", $table, implode(', ', $columns), implode(", ", $blanks));
```

And that should fix the issue you've described.

Also, while I'm here, it should be noted that you should not use `mysql_` functions anymore and move to `mysqli_` for the same type of procedure-oriented MySQL access.